# Worklight client side api query

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I used adapter based authentication and I have set the `userIdentity`. Now I was trying to get the `loginname` and `username` using the Worklight API's `WL.Client.getUserName(realm)` and `WL.Client.getLoginName(realm)`, but both the API calls return `NULL` as the result. I have set the user identity in  the adapter using the code below. I just don't know how to set the `username` and `loginname` of the user when authentication is done on adapter based authentication. I am able to retrieve the `userId` of the realm by the `WL.Client.getUserInfo(realm, "userID")`.

How do I set the `username` and `loginname`?

```
var userIdetity={
          userId : "kawin",
          disaplyName : "Kawinesh",
          attributes : {
          foo : "bar"
          }
  };
     WL.Server.setActiveUser(realmname,userIdentity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi  i have found the answer i just have to set the usrIdentity object along with the userName and loginName key value pair like

```
var userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username, 
                attributes: {
                    foo: "bar"
                },
                loginName : username,
                userName : username
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store custom attributes (as username and loginname) when creating user identity as here:

```
   var userIdetity={
          userId : "kawin",
          displayName : "Kawinesh",
          attributes : {
             username : "your_user",
             loginname : "your_login_name"                 
          }
  };

  WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);
```

Then, on the client side, you can retrieve those values getting the "attributes" object as here:

```
var attributes = WL.Client.getUserInfo("AdapterAuthRealm", "attributes");
var username = attributes.username;
var loginname = attributes.loginname;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but i found the answer what you were trying to say is to use the API WL.Client.getUserInfo("AdapterAuthRealm", "attributes"); but i was asking for the use of the API WL.Client.getUserName(realm) and WL.Client.getUserInfo(realm, "userID") and i have found the answer too. But Thanks anyway.